# Collapse all the panels in the accordion by default in extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to collapse all the panels in the accordion by default. For me first panel always active.

Guys please suggest how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ExtJS 4.2.1 you can add an extra panel, set it as hidden but expanded. You'll now be able to close all the visible panels. NOTE: This doesn't work in ExtJS 4.2.2

Answer (score 2):

Using ExtJs 4.2.2,

`collapsed: true`

in all panels, except the one you want expanded (so `collapsed: false`)

It's working for sure, code tested.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible, but if you need this config for visual purpose, you can create  a aditional, content empty panel, and put it as a last item in accordian, and make it first to expand by default, this way you can imitate *all collapsed* state! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In Accordian layout create one dummy collpased panel like

```
{
    xtype: 'panel', // << fake hidden panel
    hidden: true,
    collapsed: false
}
```

For Example
In accordian layout items

```
{
    xtype: 'panel', // << fake hidden panel
    hidden: true,
    collapsed: false
},{
    xtype:'panel',
    title:''Panle1'
},{
   xtype:'panel',
   title:''Panle2'
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

In extjs 3.2.1 at least, simply set the property

```
collapsed : true
```

on each of the panels in your accordion layout.